# i have used app.config and the connection are mentioned in connectionclass1.cs but it show the error the string contain null value

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, windows

```
public class connectionClass1
    {
       SqlConnection Con;
       SqlConnection cn;
       SqlCommand cmd;
       SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
          string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Settings.terumopenpolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        Con.Open();
        return Con;
    }

    public  connectionClass1()
    {
          string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Settings.terumopenpolConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
         SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

these was the connection string I have given but it shows the error of I didn't set the instant of object and the string contain null value

Comment: please show the bit of the app config with the connection string, you can XXX out the password etc

Comment: You have to add only name of the connectionString in the braces.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["terumopenpolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`